# How to prove that $\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$ is not free?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, free-groups

We knew that the additive group $\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$ is an abelian but non-cyclic group.

Why $\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$ is not free? But it is a free abelian group with the basis $S = \{(1; 0), (0; 1)\}.$

Thanks all for help!

Comment: ...It's a free abelian group. What's your question?

Comment: The only free group which is abelian is the free group on one generator (exercise: show that this follows from the existence of any nonabelian group whatsoever), which is cyclic.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I was going to say that. Funny terminology: There are plenty of free abelian groups out there, but only one free group which is abelian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given any two distinct element $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$, there is no homomorphism $f\colon\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\to S_3$ such that
$$
f(a)=(12)\qquad
f(b)=(13)
$$
because we'd have
$$
(132)=(12)(13)=f(a)f(b)=f(a+b)=f(b+a)=f(b)f(a)=(13)(12)=(123)
$$
which is a contradiction.

Therefore $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ cannot be free over any basis with at least two elements; on the other hand it is not a free group over one element, because $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, not being cyclic.

More generally, no two distinct elements in a basis of a free group commute, so no free group other than (up to isomorphism) $\mathbb{Z}$ is abelian.

Comment: Good! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

To understand this,  it may help to know a little *category theory*...

It depends which category you are working in...  it's free in the category of *abelian groups*, but not in the category of *groups*. ..

"Free" is a *categorical* concept,  namely that of satisfying a certain *universal property*...

It just so happens to also mean being "free" of any relations...

$a+b=b+a $ is a *relation* in the category of groups;   but not in that of abelian groups. ..

Answer (score 0):

It is a free abelian group, but not a free group.

Answer (score 0):

It is not free because $a+b=b+a$ for all $a,b$. In a free group, for two independent generators $a$ and $b$ we have $ab\ne ba$.

Note that it is a free abelian group, but *not* an abelian free group. The word order matters.